# How to write Sub query using odata

Tags: linq-to-sql, odata

I have two tables Menu and GroupMenu. I need to write sub query in Odata. I am able to get results in SQL for e.g.

```
select * from [Menu] where id in (select  MenuId from GroupMenu where GroupId = 2)
```

below is the result for the same[image]

Below is the structure of my class

```
 [Serializable]
public class GroupMenu
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MenuId")]
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(80)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your edmx ($metadata)? "subquery" have to be made via navigation properties.
something like that:

```
[...]GroupMenus?$filter=GroupId eq 2&$expand=Menu&$select=Menu
```

-it gives you GroupMenu with included Menu